# Ag-grid-Enterprise expand/collapse all row using button? Very slow crashing FF and Edge

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I created a button to expand all the rows in **ag-grid** (Enterprise) having 150 rows  in the grid. It is working fine in Chrome but it is showing an alert in the latest FF and Edge, saying the web page is making your browser slow. **Any better approach to expand all the row? It is taking almost 10-15 second**

HTML

```
<button (click)="expandAll(expand)">Expand/Collapse</button>
```

JavaScript

```
this.columnDefs = [
           {
                headerName: "",
                field: "",
                cellRenderer: "group",// for rendering cell
                suppressMenu: true,
                suppressSorting: true
            }
           ]
           // This is how I am creating fullrow width
            this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
            isFullWidthCell: function (rowNode) {
            var rowIsNestedRow = rowNode.flower;
            return rowIsNestedRow;
            },
            fullWidthCellRendererFramework: AgGridInventorRowComponent,
            doesDataFlower: function (dataItem) {
            return true;
         }
    public expandAll(value:boolean) {
            if(value) {
                this.gridOptions.api.forEachNode((node) =>{
                    node.setExpanded(true);
                });
            } else {
                this.gridOptions.api.forEachNode((node) =>{
                    node.setExpanded(false);
                });
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: can you help me on my query - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55691754/angular-ag-grid-attach-class-to-grouped-rows-cell-based-on-validation-of-other-c

Comment: @user11363823 given link is not working

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As per the documentation:

> Calling `node.setExpanded()` causes the grid to get redrawn. If you have many nodes you want to expand, then it is best to set `node.expanded=true` directly, and then call `api.onGroupExpandedOrCollapsed()` when finished to get the grid to redraw the grid again just once.

So i modified my code like below:

```
this.gridOptions.api.forEachNode(node => {
  node.expanded = true;
});
this.gridOptions.api.onGroupExpandedOrCollapsed();
```

[Ag-gridDocumentation page](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#gsc.tab=0) inside Group Api

Comment: this is the fastest and not breaking or showing alert in FF and Edge. Time consuming for 150 rows is 3-4 sec.

Comment: This will work only for clientSideModal, not for serverSideModal.

Answer (score 10):

I'm supposing that you are using the [row grouping feature](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/?framework=all#gsc.tab=0), and that you meant that there are 150 grouped rows that are able to be expanded.

Currently your code is getting executed for every single row of data... not just the ones that are able to be expanded. So supposing you have 50 rows or so of data in each group, your calling the `setExpanded` function 7500 times. You can limit this to just calling the `setExpanded` on the grouped rows by putting in a check before calling `setExpanded`:

```
public expandAll(value:boolean) {
    this.gridOptions.api.forEachNode((node) =>{
        if (node.group)
            node.setExpanded(value);
    });
}
```

testing it on [this example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/exampleSimpleRowGroup.html), it took roughly 2 seconds for 110 row groups and 5 seconds for 511 row groups in firefox

Comment: Hi @Jarod Moser thanks for your reply ....I have updated by question with more details like how I am creating grouped row. I tried the option given by you using if condition if(node.group)..for me it is false for all the node :)

Comment: You could check `node.canFlower` However, with your update I don't think that will improve performance, too much. It looks like you are using an angular component to render the full width cells. On the [performance section](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-performance/?framework=all#gsc.tab=0) of ag-grid it suggests NOT doing that to improve speed.

Comment: Thanks! Jarod... yeah as per the documentation seems like issue is with my code What i can do I will load 50-100 row in grid instead of 150 in that way it is bit faster.

Comment: Hi @Jarod any better approach for this?

Comment: Hi Jarod...I found the better approach to do this which is much faster than earlier it is mention in the documentation [https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#gsc.tab=0]

Answer (score 6):

The API has `expandAll` and `collapseAll`:

```
api.expandAll();
api.collapseAll();
```

Note that due to the crappy architecture of AG Grid the expansion state (along with row selection etc) is lost if the row data changes or the grid is re-mounted/re-rendered. You should use `deltaRowDataMode` but make sure you give your rows a unique ID to help prevent this (though this option of course can cause some hard to debug bugs which I have reported).

Also if you want to restore the user expansion in this case you have no choice but to iterate and expand/collapse individual nodes.

Also they don't seem to work on a master-detail (enterprise feature) grid...

Comment: These methods will work for only clientSideModal, not for ServerSideModal

Comment: As @SantoshKurdekar said, these methods only support client side model, they don't work for server side model.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this would help, the performance seems to be fine. Took reference from -
https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2179

But it is always better to check if the groups are present are not. That increases the performance and expanding is much much faster.

```js
    this.gridApi.forEachNode((node) => {
      if(node?.group) {
        node.setExpanded(true)
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an update as a complete solution.

Please [see this example that I created](https://plnkr.co/edit/J4mQ5aKdGxgFlPkd) o Plnkr.

Basically you can use the following code blocks **to expand and collapse** the tree data on the grid:

*At first, imports, definitions and assignments:*

```
import { GridApi } from 'ag-grid-community';
```

then:

```
gridApi!: GridApi; // variable

constructor() {}

onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent) {
  this.gridApi = params.api;
  // other codes...
}


expand() {
  this.gridApi.expandAll();
}

collapse() {
  this.gridApi.collapseAll();
}
```

However if you want to collapse and expand a specific node level groups, you can use the following examples:

```
collapse2ndLevel() {
  this.gridApi.forEachNode((node) => {
    if (node.level === 1) {
      node.setExpanded(false);
    }
  });
}

expand2ndLevel() {
  this.gridApi.forEachNode((node) => {
    if (node.level < 2 && node.isExpandable) {
      node.setExpanded(true);
    }
  });
}

collapse3rdLevel() {
  this.gridApi.forEachNode((node) => {
    if (node.level === 2 && node.isExpandable) {
      node.setExpanded(false);
    }
  });
}

expand3rdLevel() {
  this.gridApi.forEachNode((node) => {
    if (node.level < 3 && node.isExpandable) {
      node.setExpanded(true);
    }
  });
}
```

Please [check out this example that I created](https://plnkr.co/edit/J4mQ5aKdGxgFlPkd) o Plnkr.

Answer (score -2):

I use server-side row model and single decision for me it is purgeServerSideCashe() after update data. https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/23.2.0/javascript-grid-server-side-model-grouping/#example-purging-caches. It closes all expanded rows

Comment: Those mentioning the "server side model" are not technically wrong, just barking up the wrong tree. The OP is having issue with the client side model. Pointing the OP down a wholly different path is NOT a valid answer.